# How I can do binary classfication using CNN and RNN LSTM

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to deep learning and machine learning techniques. I am learning doing some examples in Python and also watching Youtube videos. 
Now I am want to do binary classification of two datasets with CNN model and RNN model to compare their performance.

The criteria is: length of data in a column is 16 then it is Class:0 otherwise class:1.

The Datasets image are attached herewith.[Class: 1 If plaintext length is 16 otherwise class: 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Okxu.jpg)

Comment: Try this https://medium.com/jatana/report-on-text-classification-using-cnn-rnn-han-f0e887214d5f

Comment: Thank you so much.